# How to get if..else work with value from FireStore Database in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase, if-statement, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to FireStore and I'm building an app for a educational institute. I have 2 different batches and each batch with 2 different classes.     {CBSE > xi, xii  &  CHSE > xi, xii}

I want the student to login to my app with FirebaseAuth and FireStore already have those students data as

```
User(collection) >> users(Document)(using the userID given by FirebaseAuth)  >>  FullName: (Student's name)
                                                                                 Phone:(number)
                                                                                 Board:(There Batch or Board, i.e., CBSE or CHSE)
                                                                                 Class:(class, i.e., XI or XII)
                                                                                 email:(email)
```

so if a student belongs to CBSE and XI, I want them to go to a different activity and if from XII of the same batch then go to a different activity. Similarly for the other Batch (CHSE) also.

I have written a code check this out

```
public class test extends AppCompatActivity {

FirebaseAuth fauth;
FirebaseFirestore fstore;
String userID, mboard, mclass;
TextView Board, Class;
private Object testB, testC;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maths);
    Board = findViewById(R.id.Board);
    Class = findViewById(R.id.Class);

    fauth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    fstore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    userID = fauth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    final DocumentReference documentReference = fstore.collection("users").document(userID);
    documentReference.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            Board.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Board"));
            Class.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Class"));
            mboard = Board.toString();
            mclass = Class.toString();
            testB = String.valueOf(documentSnapshot.getData().get(Board));
            testC = String.valueOf(documentSnapshot.getData().get(Class));


            if (testB == "CHSE") {
                if (testC == "XI") {
                    startActivity(new Intent(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class)));
                }
                if (testC == "XII") {
                    startActivity(new Intent(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),test.class)));
                }
            }
        }
    });
  }
}
```

From a YouTube tutorial I got this but with 2 problems :-
1. I have to use a textView on the layout. How can I just store the value to a variable???
2. the if...else doesn't work. I just want that to happen. How will I let students go to there respected activities with there Batch and Class????

Please help me out and thank's in advance....

Answer (score 1):

The `==` operator is not an effective way of comparing two strings in Java.  You should use the `equals()` method instead.

```
if ("CHSE".equals(testB))
```

Read: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)